# Secret.Service timeout in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, glib

I got this error in Ubuntu 16.04 when running a Python script:

```
GLib.Error: g-io-error-quark: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.secrets: 
Timeout was reached (24)
```

Code:

```py
import gi
gi.require_version('Secret', '1')
from gi.repository import Secret

flags = Secret.ServiceFlags.LOAD_COLLECTIONS
service = Secret.Service.get_sync(flags)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer by myself.

This is keyring related issue so that it happens when you invoke the service through SSH.